# Can I access the developer's console in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: pc, mass-effect-3

I know this was available in the first game, but in the second it appeared to have been deliberately disabled.  (You could make some changes to the game mechanics via .ini files, but you couldn't do this on the fly in the game.  It wasn't possible to enable the console via .ini either.)

Is the console accessible in any way in Mass Effect 3?  If so, is there any sort of command reference for it?

Answer (score 1):

The console [could be hacked "on" in a demo copy](http://blog.gib.me/2012/02/16/mass-effect-3-demo-console/), no word so far on how to do so in the retail version (nor is there a non-technically inclined method presented as yet).

However, some players have determined how to mod the game, using coalesced.bin on the retail ME3. [The tools are discussed in light detail here.](http://blog.gib.me/2012/02/16/mass-effect-3-coalesced-bin-tool/)

Specifically they're excited about the bra and panties hack nsfw at https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HOKN.jpg

Comment: Her arms look terrible. She anorexic?

Comment: @Tristan It's certainly not the physique of a professional soldier, or any other realistic body image I can dream up.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer.  I am going to leave this unaccepted for a week or two in the hopes that somebody will figure out how to do it in the retail release, but otherwise this is all yours.

Answer (score 0):

http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/PC_Tweaks_%28Mass_Effect_3%29#How_to_edit_MassEffect3.exe_with_hex-editor_to_enable_console

Instruction how to enable console in mass effect 3 full version was pasted in pastebin. From that paste, later wikia page was updated with instructions.

To enable console, masseffect3.exe file must be edited with hex-editor in one place.
This was intended for legit origin mass effect3.exe build 1.2.5427.16 and it works. 
Majority of smart people knows that origin is a spyware trojan horse and use cracks for single player. Thats why hackers found a way to do the same for 1.2.5427.16 reloaded crack, just different place in file need to be changed.

Comment: This appears to be legit, but this answer needs some more effort.  Answers that consist purely of offsite links are discouraged.  Also, can you be more specific about that last part...this requires a pirated copy?  That's not ideal.